# Decimal numbers get round up while formatting python

Tags: python, format

Here is what I have tried:

```
>>> pi = 3.14159265
>>> format(pi, '.3f') #print 3.142 # 3 precision after the decimal point
'3.142'
>>> format(pi, '.1f') #print 3.1
'3.1'
>>> format(pi, '.10f') #print 3.1415926500, more precision than the original
'3.1415926500'
>>> format(pi, '.5f') #print 3.14159, more precision than the original
'3.14159'
>>> format(pi, '.4f') 
'3.1416'
```

The concern part is this:

```
>>> format(pi, '.3f') #print 3.142 # 3 precision after the decimal point
'3.142'
>>> format(pi, '.4f') 
'3.1416'
```

Where I was expecting to have `3.1415`, I am getting `3.1416`. Please suggest me.
The SO is showing these 2 links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary
But these are not the one I am looking for.

Comment: Why is `3.1416` concerning, but `3.142` fine?

Comment: @user2357112 may be I neglected that part. But most of the concern was with 4th decimal value. Lol ... May be I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Suggest how to do what to you?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you want it to round in the correct direction?  `decimal` module has a `setcontext(ROUND_DOWN)` which may be of use. Obviously you’d have to convert your number to a `Decimal` object.

Comment: @NChauhan May be helpful but in my case I wanted to have the correct decimal. That's why I am trying to ask this query. Otherwise everything was fine,right?

Comment: @martineau I didn't got you.

Comment: What do you want a suggest about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it is `round`ing it, so it is just like the `round` function.

To fix it:

```
>>> l = str(pi).split('.')
>>> l[0] + '.' + l[1][:4]
'3.1415'
>>> float(l[0] + '.' + l[1][:4])
3.1415
```

A function version of it:

```
def first_n(a, b):
    l = str(a).split('.')
    return int(l[0] + '.' + l[1][:b])
```

And now:

```
print(first_n(pi, 4))
```

Gives:

```
3.1415
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply strip the last character:

```
pi = 3.14159

print(format(pi, '.5f')[:-1]) # 3.1415
```

Comment: But then `3.141599` still prints as `3.1416`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of suggestion you want, but here's a way to truncate a number to a given number of decimal places:

```
pi = 3.14159265

def truncate(v, places):
    return int(v * 10**places) / 10**places

print(truncate(pi, 3))  # -> 3.141
print(truncate(pi, 4))  # -> 3.1415
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. May be exactly list the answer [@U9-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56357203/9396051), a little compact.

```
>>> str(pi)[:6]
'3.1415'
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

there is `3.1416` for `format(pi, '.4f')` for the same reason there is `3.142` for `format(pi, '.3f')` - the next digit after your desired number of digits in formatted output is at least five - it is rounded up.

Comment: This is not I am expecting. I know this already that my values are getting rounded up.

Comment: So what do you expect exactly? If you just want to strip the number in sense of erasing all digits after desired place, mark @U9-Forward 's answer as correct.